# express.js routing

Tags: node.js, routes, express

Do these two express.js routes match?

```
/:campus/:tlf_id/message
/:campus/:message_id/reply
```

In express.js it seem that the do. I'm not sure I understand this correctly.

That is, if requesting `/12/90/reply` might it be caught by `/:campus/:tlf_id/message`?

Comment: They shouldn't. If you're sure that `/12/90/reply` is calling the `/:campus/:tlf_id/message` route, please report the problem: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues

Comment: Your right. It turns out I made a mistake somewhere else. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

They don't match because the 3rd url part is not prefixed with a colon. The colon prefix on the first 2 turns them into a named parameters and match anything other than `/`. The 3rd part will be a required match. So the over simplified RegEx for the routes would be `/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/message` and `/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/reply`.

Answer (score 0):

They Actually don't match.Both links are different from each other.You should add : after 3rd / for both links to be same.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 routes are not the same. because the word after the `:` determines that it's a parameter that will be used and accessed so parameters values could be equal like that `tlf_id = 12` and `message_id = 12` so the route in this case could be `/2/12` in both routes but the last keyword is what determines which route will be accessed so if both values are the same it will be

```
/2/12/message
/2/12/reply
```

so what will matter then is the last keyword you are using.